# What causes this weird response with the checkboxes react

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

In the following [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-bouman-lfi5em?file=/src/App.js) what causes the button to disable only after they have both been checked? Also is the button not displayed as disabled on render due to the way state works in react?

There are two check boxes

- I have read and agree to terms of service
- I have read and agree to the privacy agreement

I expect the submit button to be enabled only when both boxes are checked.

but instead the button becomes enabled after unchecking one of them.

here is the code

```
function App() {
  const [tosChecked, setTosChecked] = useState(false);
  const [privacyChecked, setPrivacyChecked] = useState(false);
  const [canSubmit, setCanSubmit] = useState(false);

  function handleTOSChecked(e) {
    setTosChecked(!tosChecked);
    checkCanSubmit();
  }

  function handlePrivacyChecked(e) {
    setPrivacyChecked(!privacyChecked);
    checkCanSubmit();
  }

  function checkCanSubmit() {
    if (tosChecked && privacyChecked) {
      setCanSubmit(true);
    } else {
      setCanSubmit(false);
    }
  }
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <form>
        <div className="form-control col-span-4 sm:col-span-6 lg:col-span-6">
          <label className="cursor-pointer label">
            <input
              type="checkbox"
              className="mr-2 checkbox checkbox-accent"
              checked={tosChecked}
              onChange={handleTOSChecked}
            />
            <span className="label-text">
              I have read and agree to the terms of service
            </span>
          </label>
        </div>
        <div className="form-control col-span-4 sm:col-span-4 lg:col-span-6">
          <label className="cursor-pointer label">
            <input
              type="checkbox"
              className="mr-2 checkbox checkbox-accent"
              checked={privacyChecked}
              onChange={handlePrivacyChecked}
            />
            <span className="label-text">
              I have read and agree to the privacy agreement
            </span>
          </label>
        </div>
        <button
          disabled={canSubmit}
          type="submit"
          className="btn inline-flex justify-center rounded-md border border-transparent bg-indigo-600 py-2 px-4 text-sm font-medium text-white shadow-sm hover:bg-indigo-700 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-indigo-500 focus:ring-offset-2"
        >
          Submit
        </button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set calculated property direclty, to [avoid redundant state](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/choosing-the-state-structure#avoid-redundant-state)

```
export default function App() {
  const [tosChecked, setTosChecked] = useState(false);
  const [privacyChecked, setPrivacyChecked] = useState(false);

  function handleTOSChecked(e) {
    setTosChecked((c) => !c);
    // checkCanSubmit();
  }

  function handlePrivacyChecked(e) {
    setPrivacyChecked((c) => !c);
    //  checkCanSubmit();
  }

 // set property directly
 const enableSubmit = tosChecked && privacyChecked;

 return (
   ...
   <button
          // here 
          disabled={!enableSubmit}
          type="submit"
          className="btn inline-flex justify-center rounded-md border border-transparent bg-indigo-600 py-2 px-4 text-sm font-medium text-white shadow-sm hover:bg-indigo-700 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-indigo-500 focus:ring-offset-2"
        >
```

possible reason the code was not working as expected, could be due to [batch updates](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/queueing-a-series-of-state-updates#react-batches-state-updates)
or the disable prop needed to be inverted `disabled={!canSubmit}`

```
function handleTOSChecked(e) {
    setTosChecked(!tosChecked);
    // updates inside functions are batched and flushed out on next render cycle
    if (tosChecked && privacyChecked) {
      setCanSubmit(true);
    } else {
      setCanSubmit(false);
    }
    // the values of tosChecked and privacyChecked dont change
    // similar thing must be happing even if this code is inside a function called from this code
    console.log(tosChecked, privacyChecked);
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: That works but why is the state not read on render and display the button as disabled?

Comment: I edited the answer with a brief explanation and a link to the new beta docs, hope it help